# Mmenu does not open menu unless I refresh the page

Tags: javascript, html, silverstripe, mmenu

I am building a webpage in silverstripe and I am attempting to use Mmenu.js to add a mobile menu. For some reason, if I click the menu opener, the menu will not work until I refresh the page. The url gets updated immediately, but nothing else happens.

I have tried googling this but every suggestion I have found so far has not worked.

Currently I'm using version 8.2.3 because when I tried the latest version, I would get the error "Mmenu is undefined" when running my `mmenu_init.js` script.

Heres the general layout of my page:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery.mmenu/8.2.3/mmenu.css" integrity="sha256-XULUJ0ERBgEKrcR3CENdFRfSwMKwMJn3KuD9MjuAoVg=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="page_container">
      <header>
        <a id="hamburger" class="mobile_only" href="/new_site/test/public/#mobile_nav">Open menu</a>
        <nav id="mobile_nav">
      <ul>
        <li class="active">
          <a href="/new_site/test/public/" title="Home">Home</a>
          <li >
        <a href="/new_site/test/public/about/" title="About">About</a>
        <ul>
          <li >
            <a href="/new_site/test/public/about/mission/" title="Mission">Mission</a>
          </li>
          <li >
            <a href="/new_site/test/public/about/history/" title="History">History</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
          </li>
          <li >
        <a href="/new_site/test/public/newsletters/" title="Newsletters">Newsletters</a>
        <ul>
          <li >
            <a href="/new_site/test/public/newsletters/recent/" title="Recent">Recent</a>
          </li>
          <li >
            <a href="/new_site/test/public/newsletters/archives/" title="Archives">Archives</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
          </li>
          <li >
        <a href="/new_site/test/public/events/" title="Events">Events</a>
        <ul>
          <li >
            <a href="/new_site/test/public/events/past/" title="Past">Past</a>
          </li>
          <li >
            <a href="/new_site/test/public/events/announcements/" title="Announcements">Announcements</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
          </li>
          <li >
        <a href="/new_site/test/public/resources/" title="Resources">Resources</a>  
        <ul>      
          <li >
            <a href="/new_site/test/public/resources/policy/" title="Policy">Policy</a>
          </li>   
          <li >
            <a href="/new_site/test/public/resources/books/" title="Books">Books</a>
          </li>   
          <li >
            <a href="/new_site/test/public/resources/other-books/" title="Other Books">Other Books</a>
          </li>   
          <li >
            <a href="/new_site/test/public/resources/links/" title="Links">Links</a>
          </li>   
        </ul>
          </li>      
      </ul>
    </nav>
      </header>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery.mmenu/8.2.3/mmenu.js" integrity="sha256-eSVpPcpo6qwKHLSpc7SWDKDG3TjMNxlFzbtfcJIJQjI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="mmenu_init.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is `mmenu_init.js`:

```
Mmenu.configs.classNames.selected = "active";
Mmenu.configs.offCanvas.page.selector = "#page_container";

document.addEventListener(
    "DOMContentLoaded", () => {
        window.menu = new Mmenu( "#mobile_nav", {
            extensions: ["theme-dark"]
        });
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was a problem with silverstripe rewriting ajex requests (see https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/templates/how_tos/disable_anchor_links/).

To fix this, i added this to my `app/_config/app.yml`:

```
SilverStripe\View\SSViewer:
  rewrite_hash_links: false
```